# Writing result of SinkTask to topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

I am developing a Sink Connector for kafka that reads events from a topic, process them and translate them to data in a RedisDB. I am interested on producing the result of my redis writing query to another topic so I can consume from it for other pourposes. So the last thing in my put() method in the SinkTask would be a "produce some information that I already got in a variable, as a result of the redis query, to a kafka topic".
I have seen Confluent Kafka Connect has a Connect Reporter topic implementation that can be used and it seems to be what I am looking for, but I am not using confluent kafka and neither will I change to it so I don't know if there is any clean solution to this, or alternative, in bare apache kafka.

Would be any problem adding a Kafka Producer in each of my Sink Tasks in order to able them to produce to a Kafka Topic after doing the processing in put()?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Kafka Connect nor Interceptors are specific to Confluent, but what's stopping you from instantiating a Producer?

Comment: I'm not aware of any clean solution. Having a custom producer is the only way which somes up to my mind. One thing I'm not sure about is how would your custom producer be configured. When I saw it in the past, it always used a separate configuration for where to connect, credentials etc. That makes configuring it painful for the user which use security and ecnryption etc.. But I'm not sure this can be worked around in any way. The connector probably doesn't have access to the complete Connect configuration to just re-use it.

Comment: What I have actually done is to include a producer on each connector task